# How to turn chrome_url_override on and off without removing the extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In my manifest.json file, I set up a chrome_url_override on chrome://history. I'm trying to turn that override off and on based on whether a given condition is fulfilled or not. How can I do this? Is there any way to change it without having to remove the extension?

I've tried using chrome.tab.update and chrome.tab.create, but neither do anything to turn off the override.